# How to apply a null-check within Stream#map()

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream, nullable

I have the following piece of code:

```
 myList.getJumps().stream()
            .map(step -> step.getJump().getValue())
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There is a chance that `step.getJump()` can be `null`.

Is there an efficient way to avoid a *NPE* there?

Comment: why not filter `step.getJump() != null`

Answer (score 1):

As @HariHaravelan mentioned in comments:

```
myList.getJumps().stream()
            .filter(step-> step.getJump()! = null)
            .map(step -> step.getJump().getValue())
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or even:

```
myList.getJumps().stream()
                .filter(step-> Objects.nonNull(step.getJump())
                .map(step -> step.getJump().getValue())
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: There’s no reason to use a `map` step, to be immediately followed by `flatMap`. A single step is enough: `.flatMap(step -> step.getJump().getValue().stream())`. On the other hand, repeated calls to `getJump` could be avoided: `myList.getJumps().stream() .map(Step::getJump) .filter(Objects::nonNull) .flatMap(step -> step.getValue().stream()) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with explicate *null-check*. If we apply it inside the `flatMap()` operation a non-null list `step.getJump()` should spawn a *stream*, otherwise an *empty stream* needs to be provided:

```
myList.getJumps().stream()
    .flatMap(step -> step.getJump() != null ?
        jump.getValue().stream() : Stream.empty())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Starting with Java 9 we can utilize `Stream.ofNullable()` that creates either a *singleton stream* or an *empty stream*:

```
myList.getJumps().stream()
    .flatMap(step -> Stream.ofNullable(step.getJump())
        .flatMap(jump -> jump.getValue().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```